# Angular save form field in each dynamic tab to a FormGroup

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

In html I can able to create dynamic tab with form, but I couldn't able to save form table from each tab. Please help me to save this data.

Save all fields in M1 tab and additional tabs like a nested group.

eg: Tab={'M1':{nameid:'xxx',height:'177',weight:'80',etc},'M2':{nameid:'yyy',height:'167',weight:'50',etc}

I shared the code link below,
https://angular-mqst65.stackblitz.io

Thanks in advance.

i tried to create the form array for each tab. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of create an array of FormGroup, you can use a FormArray of FormGroups to mannage together all the data.

First create a function that create the formGroup and define tab as FormArray

```
  tab: FormArray=null

  createGroup()
  {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      measuretype: '',
      nameid: '',
      height: '',
      weight: '',
      birthday: '',
      gender: '',
    });
  }
```

In constructor create the formArray with one element

```
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.tab=this._formBuilder.array([this.createGroup()]);
  }
```

We need a function that return the element of the FormArray as FormGroup

```
  getTabForm(index:number)
  {
    return this.tab.at(index) as FormGroup
  }
```

Well, as always we have a FormArray we iterate over the formArray.controls, not over the "tabs" array

```
<mat-tab-group #mattab  >
    <!--see that you iterate over tab.controls-->
    <!--and use tabs[index] to give value to the "label"-->
    <mat-tab
      *ngFor="let group of tab.controls; let index = index"
      [label]="tabs[index]"
    >
      <!--here a div with fromGroup getTabForm(index)-->
      <div [formGroup]="getTabForm(index)">
         ..your inputs here..
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

When add and remove futhermore change the array "tabs" with the labels, we add/remove the element of formArray. See that when add we pass the mat-group to allow us change the active index

```
<!--the "mattab" is the template reference variable of the mat-tab-group-->
<button mat-raised-button class="example-add-tab-button"
   (click)="addTab(mattab);">
              Add
</button>
```

So the functions becomes like

```
  addTab(tabGroup: MatTabGroup) {
    this.tabs.push('M' + (this.tabs.length + 1));
    this.tab.push(this.createGroup())
    tabGroup.selectedIndex=this.tabs.length-1;

  }

  removeTab(index: number) {
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    this.tab.removeAt(index)
  }
```

I add in the .html

```
<pre>
  {{tab?.value|json}}
</pre>
```

To see the values of the formArray

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqst65-srfujw?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts) with the changes

NOTE: I choose use a formArray directly -without include in a formGroup-

**Update** If we want not use a FormArray else an Array of FormGroups (our formGroups has differenct structure) is much more like

```
tab: FormGroup[]=[] //<--instead of a FormArray

//really we can replace in our .html
getTabForm(index:number)
{
    return this.tab[index] as FormGroup
}

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    //see that it's not a formArray else a simple Array of FormGroups
    this.tab=[this.createGroup()];
}

addTab(tabGroup: MatTabGroup,index:number) {
    this.tabs.push('M' + (this.tabs.length + 1));
    //really here we should call to a function createGroup that 
    //depends from the index or another variable
    this.tab.push(this.createGroup())
    tabGroup.selectedIndex=this.tabs.length-1;
  }

removeTab(index: number) {
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    //simply remove the element in the array "tabs"
    this.tab.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

The tabGroup

```
<mat-tab-group #mattab  >
    <!--now not iterate over tab.controls, simply over tab-->
    <mat-tab
      *ngFor="let group of tab; let index = index"
      [label]="tabs[index]"
    >
      <!--here we can use the "group" variable
          So, it's uneccesary the function getTabForm   -->
      <div [formGroup]="group">

         <!--here we can use a ng-container switch-->
         <ng-container [ngSwitch]="tabs[index]">
           <table style="width: 100%" *ngSwitchCase="'M1'">
                    ....
           </table>
           <table style="width: 100%" *ngSwitchCase="'M2'">
                    ....
           </table>
         </ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Finally, **only** to "check" we can add a getter function

```
get tabValue()
{
    return this.tab.map(x=>x.value)
}
```

to write

```
<pre>
  {{tabValue|json}}
</pre>
```

A [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqst65-2hyxtj?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts). (In the stackblitz I use as ngSwitch index%2 to simulate different forms)

Comment: @Kenny46k, updated the answer and add a new stackblitz to give an idea as how solve the question. NOTE: Really use a large switch case it's not the ideal